# Zend Framework: Controller class == Page?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Am I right in thinking that in Zend Framework, if I plan to have 5 pages at my site, I'd generally need 5 controllers? Do ZF developers typically create 1 controller per page ("page" as abtract app unit)?

The reason I am asking this is that previously for some reason I stuffed a lot of various actions into controllers so that they played role of pages, e.g. index/add, index/view, index/delete and displayed various small screens, e.g. small CRUD screens as opposed to grids displayed by index action.

But as of now I want to check my new understanding that actions are needed mostly for model updates and actions should, once run, immediately redirect back to controller/index. So it seems that views should mostly be used in index actions, and less frequently in other actions.

Does this sound architecturally valid?

Comment: does anyone have any sources of information for designing your zend controller structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose thats one way of doing it... Using your analogy i suppose i use a controller like a "section" and actions like "pages" to those sections.

But thats getting stuck more on the old procedural||static paradigm of pages because really the action controller itself has no more to do with a page or section than the association you make as a developer. Ie. each page can potentially be a composite of numerous actions and views depening on the application's architecture.

For example if i have a blog modules i might have the following:

Controllers:

- PostController
- CommentController

Views:

- post

  - display (display a single post)
  - list (list posts)
  - edit (create/edit post)
- comment

  - display (display n comments)
  - list (list comments)
  - edit (create/edit/moderate comment)
  - embed-list (for use on the Post itself assuming this differs from display)

Comment: How would you then organize the display of Post with its Comments below? Shouldn't "display x coments" action go into Post controller?

Comment: Not IMO. display n comments doesnt display the post at all... it jsut displays n comments for a given post.

To emebd the comments below the post i would in my PostController::displayAction set a variable for the view containing the comments as an array or collection object. then in the display view for a post i would simply call the embed-list or display view from comment - depending on whether the two views differ at all.

Comment: ofcourse passing that comment variable through the partial helper like so:

$this->partial('comment/display.phtml', array('comments'=>$this->comments));

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a controller should always group multiple methods that have a common use case. Try to find "nouns", that describe the functionality of your app: those are the controllers (while verbs are the controller methods).

If you have (for example) a blog, you may have:

- ArticleListController (listing all
  articles, listing the top 10, listing
  all articles for a tag,...)
- SingleArticleController (displaying one article, adding comments,...)
- AdminController (lets you write Articles)

If you have just 5 pages (e.g. home, about, contact,...) the MVC architecture might not be the right fit.

Answer (score 1):

**indexAction** is merely the default action for a given controller, useful for displaying a default view (the same as displaying the index.html or index.php page for a sub-directory).

It is completely acceptable to create a variety of actions on a per controller basis that may or may not each have their own views (*i.e.* add and edit).  The controller is intended to group similar actions.

For example usage please refer to the documentation on [Zend_Controller_Action](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html).  You may also find it useful to familiarize yourself with the workflow of [Zend_Controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.basics.html).